# Can one debug HLSL on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, graphics, windows-phone-8, directx, hlsl

The more I look around, the more it looks like this feature just isn't supported.

When I try to run the graphics diagnostics tools, it just launches the app and debugs normally. I see nothing new that is related to graphics anywhere on the screen (every button on the graphics toolbar is grayed out).

I'm surprised I wasn't able to get an answer from my search engine, but I would love guidance so I could try some other form of debugging instead.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Have you tried using a tool such as https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition ? I haven't checked whether it works with mobile graphics accelerators, though.

Comment: I haven't, but I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Sadly it looks like it can't debug any non-NVidia GPU, much less a fellow ARM competitor's (Qualcomm) chip. Thanks for the lead though